# How to decrease the size of an image texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, image

[image: Example Of My Problem]

ok so as you can see in the image above, I have made 3 materials using cycles render (the wood, gravel and metal). No nodes. My wood texture came out great. My gravel texture seems super stretched. The actual image I'm using is much more detailed than bender is making it out to be. Any suggestions? I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: You have scale options on the texture tab (just on the right of the material tab)

Comment: Oh wow :/, thanks! Glad it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have scaling options under Texture > Mapping

Comment: When questions are answered in the comments, follow the agreed procedures as decided my the community in [Meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments).

Comment: Sorry about that.  I didn't read the comments.